# Using Single Property to set *ngif = false for others

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to update values coming from db.
I am using ngModel to set values in the textbox as I click the update button. but for all the other records the textbox are getting open.

Code...
HTML

```
<li  *ngFor="let t of Tutorials ; let i = index">
      {{t.name}} --- {{t.url}}
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="tutName" *ngIf="update">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="tutUrl" *ngIf="update">
      <button (click)="updateTut(t)">Update</button>
</li>
```

read.ts

```
    update : boolean = false;
updateTut(tut : Tutorial){
      this.update = !this.update;
      if(this.update){
        this.tutName = tut.name;
        this.tutUrl = tut.url;
        this.update = !this.update;
}
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) Can you please add a fiddle with your code

Comment: you're toggling the value of update and if the toggle value is true, you're making it false. Is that what you intend to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a property call `update` in the array objects and update that one

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="tutName" *ngIf="t.update">

updateTut(tut : Tutorial){
      tut .update = !tut .update;
      if(this.update){
        this.tutName = tut.name;
        this.tutUrl = tut.url;
        tut.update = !tut.update;
}
```

Comment: @Archit Goel - this is your method. Every time you get an update from the DB - use `.forEach` to append the `update` property to it

Comment: @OmerShukar though it is working fine, is it a feasible solution??

Comment: @ArchitGoel It is the most feasible of all. You will find yourself appending dynamic data to many sorts of DB objects in a regular basis

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `update` variable which is being shared by all the `Tutorials`.

I would have suggested to have update property in tutorial but as you said its coming from DB so I won't suggest to modify it. So just introduce one more `variable` call `currentIndex` and track the current selected item.

### in html

```
<li  *ngFor="let t of Tutorials ; let i = index">
      {{t.name}} --- {{t.url}}
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="tutName" *ngIf="i == currentIndex ">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="tutUrl" *ngIf="i == currentIndex">
      <button (click)="updateTut(t,i)">Update</button>
</li>
```

### in ts

```
update : boolean = false;
currentIndex = -1;
updateTut(tut : Tutorial, index){
      this.currentIndex = index;
      this.tutName = tut.name;
      this.tutUrl = tut.url;
}
```